# Scikit learn: Interpolation with linearRegression does not work

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression, interpolation

I am trying to perform interpolation using Scikit learn's LineaerRegression class, but the result seems wrong. The idea is to use a polynomial fit with a degree equal to the number of observations minus one. This should make the linearRegression estimator produce an interpolation. However, LinearRegression does not give an interpolation solution.

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

# Data
x = np.array([65.44, 65.99, 65.16, 66.24, 66.85, 66.78, 67.52, 65.1 , 62.72,
       63.53, 63.62, 64.23, 64.89, 64.3 , 66.41])
y = np.array([8.5503, 8.5596, 8.4819, 8.505 , 8.5137, 8.5174, 8.5183, 8.5336,
       8.5581, 8.5534, 8.531 , 8.5546, 8.6349, 8.6553, 8.639 ])

# Design matrix with polynomial degree corresponding to the number of points (interpolation)
polyEstimator = PolynomialFeatures(len(x) - 1)
XHat = polyEstimator.fit_transform(x.reshape(-1, 1))

# Regression 
linReg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False) #normalize=True, 
linRegFit = linReg.fit(XHat, y)
yPredict = linRegFit.predict(XHat)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, yPredict, label='Fit')
plt.plot(x, y, 'x', label='True')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

I have tried with normalize=True, but also that did not give the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to predict in ascending order of `x`. I solved this by putting your data into a DataFrame and then sort by `x`. If you predict into that dataframe, the plot is correct. You need the Dataframe structure because you can't sort on `x` alone. This would invalidate your `(x,y)` pairs.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
import pandas as pd
# Data
x = np.array([65.44, 65.99, 65.16, 66.24, 66.85, 66.78, 67.52, 65.1 , 62.72,
       63.53, 63.62, 64.23, 64.89, 64.3 , 66.41])
y = np.array([8.5503, 8.5596, 8.4819, 8.505 , 8.5137, 8.5174, 8.5183, 8.5336,
       8.5581, 8.5534, 8.531 , 8.5546, 8.6349, 8.6553, 8.639 ])

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
df = df.sort_values(by='x')

# Design matrix with polynomial degree corresponding to the number of points (interpolation)
polyEstimator = PolynomialFeatures(len(x) - 1)
XHat = polyEstimator.fit_transform(np.array(df['x']).reshape(-1, 1))

# Regression
linReg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False) #normalize=True,
linRegFit = linReg.fit(XHat, df['y'])
df['yPredict'] = linRegFit.predict(XHat)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df['x'], df['yPredict'], label='Fit')
plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'], 'x', label='True')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering @E. Sommer. I tried your code, but the result is still not correct on my computer. The plot looks different, but still not correct.

Comment: are you saying your plot looks different than mine, apart from matplotlib style? what do you mean by "not correct"? Your estimation is working fine, your plot is screwed only because the plot goes back and forth on the x axis due to `x` being unsorted.

Comment: Sorry, I get the same plot as you do. The estimated line should cross all the points, since the polynomial degree equals the number of points minus 1, and this does not happen. This goes independently on the ordering of the observations I think.

Comment: I don't think your reasoning is right. Just because you fit a very flexible polynom does not mean you hit all your data points. Maybe this is better asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think the solutoin should cross all points when the polynomial degree equals the number of observations minus 1, see e.g. the section "Unisolvence Theorem" on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation I'll check your link.